# Nothing is displayed when I change the code of component in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a component which displays the `card` of material UI. 
Below code works fine and the component gets displayed (see screenshot):

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';


const UserManagement = () => (
  <Card>
    <CardHeader
      title="Without Avatar"
      subtitle="Subtitle"
      actAsExpander={true}
      showExpandableButton={true}
    />
    <CardActions>
      <FlatButton label="Action1" />
      <FlatButton label="Action2" />
    </CardActions>
    <CardText expandable={true}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
      Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
      Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
    </CardText>
  </Card>
);

export default UserManagement;
```

As soon as I change above code to following code nothing is displayed. I get a blank screen why so ?

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
    <CardHeader
      title="Without Avatar"
      subtitle="Subtitle"
      actAsExpander={true}
      showExpandableButton={true}
    />
    <CardActions>
      <FlatButton label="Action1" />
      <FlatButton label="Action2" />
    </CardActions>
    <CardText expandable={true}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
      Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
      Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
    </CardText>
  </Card>
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Ouptut of first code snippet:
[image]

Comment: Component would be undefined I guess.. probably you meant React.Component

Comment: You need to extend `React.Component`, or Import `Component` as well

Comment: @Avinash I could not understand what are you trying to say ? Why does my 2nd code snippet does not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
    <CardHeader
      title="Without Avatar"
      subtitle="Subtitle"
      actAsExpander={true}
      showExpandableButton={true}
    />
    <CardActions>
      <FlatButton label="Action1" />
      <FlatButton label="Action2" />
    </CardActions>
    <CardText expandable={true}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
      Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
      Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
    </CardText>
  </Card>
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Component is not defined, it should be React.Component

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions are correct but you can try this instead of React.component,actually its a old method.
You can use this also

import React, { Component } from 'react'